# Generic type 'Dispatch<S>' requires 1 type argument(s). TS2314

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I cloned a react project in my Mac which was probably developed under Windows.

I did `yarn add react-scripts` and `yarn install`, `package.json` is as follows. Then `PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` returned the following error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/tmp/10Studio/frontend/src/components/NoAuthLoginRedirect/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/tmp/10Studio/frontend/src/components/NoAuthLoginRedirect/index.tsx(18,13):
Generic type 'Dispatch<S>' requires 1 type argument(s).  TS2314

    16 | import { getAppSubscribePage } from '../../services/app-utils';
    17 | export interface INoAuthLoginRedirectProps {
  > 18 |   dispatch: Dispatch;
       |             ^
    19 |   onDissmiss?: Function;
    20 |   next?: string;
    21 |   subscription?: Subscription;
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
    "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.4",
    "@uifabric/react-cards": "^0.109.49",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "cross-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "dva": "^2.4.1",
    "dva-model-creator": "^0.4.3",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.20.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.105.4",
    "query-string": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-monaco-editor": "^0.35.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SET PORT=8000 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8096 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/color": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/cross-storage": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.5",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.33"
  }
}
```

Here is a part of that `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { Dialog, getId, DialogType, Stack, Text } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

import { State } from '../../store/reducer';
import { getNextPath } from '../../selectors/header';
import { getSubscription, getTrial } from '../../selectors/subscription';
import { Subscription } from '../../services/subscription';
import { getIsSubscriptionActive, getPlanProductName } from '../Plans/utils';
import { selectAppName } from '../../selectors/app';
import { AppName } from '../../models/app';
import { getAppSubscribePage } from '../../services/app-utils';
export interface INoAuthLoginRedirectProps {
  dispatch: Dispatch;
  onDissmiss?: Function;
  next?: string;
  subscription?: Subscription;
  trial: Subscription;
  feature: string;
  app: AppName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is that the type 'Dispatch' is generic but you did not provide a Type to it.

Make sure the import is from the module that you actually want since 'Dispatch' could also be used in a module that you may have imported by accident.

Other than that, to fix it quickly you can turn

```
dispatch: Dispatch;
```

into

```
dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
```

and see if the app compiles.